# Howto translte this curl post into php

Tags: php, curl

i have this example curl post on cli:

```
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: text/plain" --header "Accept: application/json" -d "25" "http://{IP}:8080/rest/items/item"
```

I dont want to "exec" this in php, but use builtin php functions.

Bfo

Comment: What have you attempted so far before asking other people for their time to help? Where are you stuck? Have you done any basic research into this topic? Try https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ first to convert it automatically. if that doesn't fully succeed then post the PHP code it generates here and explain what problem you had when you ran it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: the `$result` is your JSON-Object you recived from the URL.

```
<?php
$headers = [
    'Content-Type: text/plain',
    'Accept: application/json'
];
$url = 'http://{IP}:8080/rest/items/item';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 25);

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
if (curl_errno($ch))
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($result);
```

i hope this is want you want/need/mean with "builtin functions".